# VBA Macro to save excel analysis as UTF-8 textfile

Tags: vba, excel, utf-8

I have an XLS file containing some foreign characters.
I have tried the following approach, but the data looks funky:

```
--- removed code above
wb.SaveAs fPath & Replace(fName, ".xlsx", ".txt"), FileFormat:=xlUnicodeText, CreateBackup:=False
wb.Saved = True
wb.Close True
ActiveWorkbook.Close


tFileToOpenPath = fPath & Replace(fName, ".xlsx", ".txt")
tFileToSavePath = fPath & Replace(fName, ".xlsx", "-UTF8.txt")

Dim oStream
Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream") 'Create Stream object 
With oStream
    .Type = 2 'Specify stream type – we want To save text/string data. 
    .CharSet = "utf-8" 'Specify charset For the source text data. 
    .Open 'Open the stream 
    .LoadFromFile tFileToOpenPath  'And write the file to the object stream 
    .SaveToFile tFileToSavePath, 2  'Save the data to the named path 
End With
Set oStream = Nothing 'Close the stream - no memory leaks
```

The output data looks like that... I'm puzzled

```
S a l e s
```

The txt file itself is fine, just the UTF-8.txt one is really weird

Thanks!

Comment: @vba4all I'm sure you mean well, but I'm sorry I don't see how to adapt your answer to my problem...

Comment: i have no idea how this got posted to here. I have deleted it already, sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what happens:
`wb.SaveAs` saves your workbook as `xlUnicodeText`. This is in fact UTF16LE (which is mostly meant when anyone just says 'Unicode').

Your Stream Object opens this UTF16 source, but reads it as UTF8. In UTF16, characters take up a minimum of two bytes. In UTF8, simple latin characters only use one byte, hence an empty byte after most characters (displayed in your case as spaces; notepad++ would display <kbd>NUL</kbd>).

This seems to work for a conversion:

```
Public Sub convert_UnicodeToUTF8(parF1 As String, parF2 As String)
    Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2
    Const adTypeText = 2

    Dim streamSrc, streamDst ' Source / Destination
    Set streamSrc = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    Set streamDst = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    streamDst.Type = adTypeText
    streamDst.Charset = "utf-8"
    streamDst.Open

    With streamSrc
        .Type = adTypeText
        .Charset = "Unicode" ' this is also the default value
        .Open
        .LoadFromFile parF1
        .copyTo streamDst
        .Close
    End With
    streamDst.saveToFile parF2, adSaveCreateOverWrite
    streamDst.Close
    Set streamSrc = Nothing
    Set streamDst = Nothing

End Sub
```

See [ADODB.Stream.CopyTo](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_stream_copyto.asp).

> the CharSet property of the destination Stream object can be different than the source Stream object`

Comment: I am trying to load this file with informatica, which can only read UTF-8. So I need to convert it...

Comment: Ok, I see, you can probably convert it with two stream objects,... I'll try it too